# Android Task :app:lint - Runtime JAR file has version older than required for API version

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I was trying to build an Android App using React-Native. While adding Facebook Login functionality I ran into a weird issue giving me the below error:

```
> Task :app:lint
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.3, which is older than the API version 1.4. Consider using the runtime of version 1.4, or pass '-api-version 1.3' explicitly to restrict the available APIs to the runtime of version 1.3. You can also pass '-language-version 1.3' instead, which will restrict not only the APIs to the specified version, but also the language features
w: C:\Users\your-machine\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.31\20c34a04ea25cb1ef0139598bd67c764562cb170\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.31.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.3 which is older than required for API version 1.4
w: C:\Users\your-machine\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.3.31\e652770b6416c6d85934086899ffed3eccd35813\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.31.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.3 which is older than required for API version 1.4
w: C:\Users\your-machine\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.31\11289d20fd95ae219333f3456072be9f081c30cc\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.31.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.3 which is older than required for API version 1.4
w: C:\Users\your-machine\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.31\20c34a04ea25cb1ef0139598bd67c764562cb170\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.31.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.3 which is older than required for API version 1.4
```

I do understand that this is something to do with my Kotlin configuration, but I have not done any configuration on my own so far. It is all default which comes with React-Native.

Any suggestion what the issue is and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions of dependencies mentioned in logs
eg: \kotlin-stdlib-common has added version of 1.3.31 where the latest one is 1.4

Change the dependencies to the latest versions in your build.gradle file or check for there instances in your maven dependency injection files (if used)

and rebuid the project